# Batch file detect if specific tab is open?

Tags: batch-file, detection, detect

I want to let my script check, if a specific tab is open or not in google chrome, for example "https://stackoverflow.com/".

I know how to check if the browser runs at all, but I am not sure, if it's possible to let check it if an specific tab is open.

Does someone has an idea, how i could realize this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort of..

First you need [OpenList](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/openlist/nkpjembldfckmdchbdiclhfedcngbgnl/related?hl=en) extension for chrome.Then you need [snedkeys.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/sendKeys.bat). This is a script in the same directory as the snedKeys.bat.It will list all opened links in chrome:

```
@echo off

start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" "chrome-extension://nkpjembldfckmdchbdiclhfedcngbgnl/popup.html?focusHack"

::sleeps for 5 seconds
w32tm /stripchart /computer:localhost /period:1 /dataonly /samples:5  >nul 2>&1

::call sendKeys.bat ""  "^A"

::w32tm /stripchart /computer:localhost /period:1 /dataonly /samples:5  >nul 2>&1

call sendKeys.bat ""  "^c"

w32tm /stripchart /computer:localhost /period:1 /dataonly /samples:5  >nul 2>&1

for /f "usebackq tokens=* delims=" %%i in (
   `mshta "javascript:Code(close(new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject').GetStandardStream(1).Write(clipboardData.getData('Text'))));"`
) do (
 echo cntent of the clipboard:
 echo "%%i"
)
```

You can filter the result with FINDSTR or FIND to check if desired link is open.

E.g. this will check if stackoverflow is open:

```
@echo off

start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" "chrome-extension://nkpjembldfckmdchbdiclhfedcngbgnl/popup.html?focusHack"

::sleeps for 5 seconds
w32tm /stripchart /computer:localhost /period:1 /dataonly /samples:5  >nul 2>&1

call sendKeys.bat ""  "^c"

for /f "usebackq tokens=* delims=" %%i in (
   `mshta "javascript:Code(close(new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject').GetStandardStream(1).Write(clipboardData.getData('Text'))));"`
) do (
 echo "%%i"| find "stackoverflow" >nul 2>&1 && (
    echo stackoverflow is open
 )
)

call sendKeys.bat ""  "^w"
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes:

```
tasklist /V | find /i "chrome"
```

will show you the title of the open tab that has focus.

Comment: It will show you the title of the tab that has focus. That's something.

Comment: here's a cleaner way `tasklist  /v /fi  "IMAGENAME eq  chrome.exe" /fo "list" | find "Window Title:" | find /v "N/A"`