# Run php cron job on same Chrome tab

Tags: php, google-chrome, cron, xampp, scheduled-tasks

I have a Cron job which launches a Chrome window every time it runs and points to a php script running with xampp in background.

The problem is every minute it opens a new chrome tab, how can i make it so it just updates a single tab in the background?

The .bat file i use to run it:

```
set doc=C:\xampp\htdocs\bot
cd "%doc%"
copy /y nul "file.php"
ECHO ^<?php echo 'This is executed via scheduler task!'; ?^> >file.php
schtasks /create /tn "Cron" /tr "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe http://localhost/bot/bot.php" /sc minute /mo 1
```

Comment: Have a look at this SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34671901/batch-file-detect-if-specific-tab-is-open  ... maybe this helps. Do you need the browser window for any specific purpose? If not, just call php cli. If yes, maybe think about a minor redesign so you start the browser once and trigger the request regularly via jscript (ajax).

Answer (score 1):

You can run the job in php cli, to do that add php in system path or copy the full path of `php.exe` and then user `php your-file.php` or `c:\wamp\....\php.exe your-file.php`. This way you can run this job in the background.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of search i eventualy took a simpler way around.

I set my cronjob to run in php cli as suggested here, by including the php-win.exe file as such:

```
set doc=C:\xampp\htdocs\bot
cd "%doc%"
copy /y nul "file.php"
ECHO ^<?php echo 'This is executed via scheduler task!'; ?^> >file.php
schtasks /create /tn "Cron" /tr "C:\xampp\php\php-win.exe http://localhost/bot.php" /sc minute /mo 1
```

Then i just created another php file that draw the output from the main php script.

Output.php:

```
<?php
ob_start();
include("bot.php");
$a= ob_get_clean();
echo "Hello, $a!";
?>
```

Lastly, i run the output on a chrome tab and refresh when needed:

> http://localhost/bot/output.php